# User's role - Use Gate or without?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need to implement simple User Role such as Admin, Moderator, and Analytics.

I don't need to add permission/features on each role. A user can be assigned to 1 role only.

There might be many way to implement this in Laravel, I am looking decent way implementing this and secure.

Would `Gate` facade be right approach for this? Or create a `Role` model with methods. Something like:
`if ($user->hasRole(['admin', 'moderator'])) { //can view this feature }` in blade or controller. There might be a cleaner way than this and role check in middleware.

Comment: Middleware is probably the best for this; wrap routes in `auth.{role}` middleware, check for `Auth::user()->inRole("whatever");` and reject (`abort(401);`) if they aren't in that role. Combine that with a middleware to check for a User actually being logged in and you're golden. Probably a little broad of a question for SO though. Personally never used `Gate`, so can't comment on that.

Comment: @TimLewis What about in Blade? Role X and Y have access some features in a page

Comment: Then it get's complicated; you'd either need a middleware for each role combination, like `auth.adminOrModerator`, or scrap that all together and use local checks like you have above `@if($user->canDoWhatever()) ... @endif`. Definitely too broad for SO now :P

Comment: I like to use this https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission

Comment: I would recommend using policies for this matter. First, in your views you can use @can and @cannot in your views. Then, if you want to protect certain routes, you can use a middleware named "can". Finally, if you need more precise protection, you can always call either the method `can` on your user or the facade `Gate`. More here : https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authorization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regardless of whether you use [**Middleware**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware), [**Request** authorize method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#form-request-validation), [**Policies**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authorization#authorizing-actions-using-policies) or [**Gates**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authorization#authorizing-actions-via-gates) (which can be used as a Middleware), you would still need `Role` model.

`Roles` table will be the place you store all the roles and attach them to users by their name or slugs.

1. **Create a `Role` model.**

   - Id
   - Name
2. **If you're sure, that a user can only have 1 `Role`, then add `role_id` to your `users` table.**
3. **Add the [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships) inside the `User` and `Role` models.**

`User.php`

```
public function role()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Role::class);
}
```

`Role.php`

```
public function user()
{
     return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

4. **In your `AuthServiceProvider.php`, you can [define the gates](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authorization#writing-gates):**

*(assuming role_id is not nullable)*

```
Gate::define('do-this', function ($user) {
    return in_array($user->role->name, DoThisClass::allowedRoles());
});
```

5. **In your blades, you can check if the user has permission for certain tasks using [@can directives.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authorization#via-blade-templates):**

   ```
   @can('do-this')
       <button>You can definitely do this!</button>
   @endcan
   ```
6. **In your Routes, you can check if user is authorized by using [Gates as a Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authorization#authorizing-actions-using-policies):**

   ```
   Route::group(['middleware' => ['can:do-this']], function () {
       Route::get('do-this', 'DoThisController@action');
   });
   ```

**Why should you tie Gates with names rather than ID of Roles?**

Since Roles can be deleted and it's super unreadable to use their ID, I would recommend using Role names.

The IDs can mismatch in the code and the databases when different enviroments are used.

Comment: Great answer. Can you provide example of `DoThisClass::allowedRoles()` please? Thing is I don't need to define a list of features/permissions for a role.

Comment: Something like that I need would be good `@canany(['admin', 'moderator'])   <button>You can definitely do this!</button> @endcan`

Comment: `@can` can only check 1 gate.

The simplest way to do this, just hardcode array in the Gate.

Gate::define('moderate', function ($user) {
    return in_array($user->role->name, ['admin', 'moderator']);
});

Then you can use `@can('moderate')`.

I just would advise you to move `['admin', 'moderator']` somewhere else to be more dynamic :)

Comment: `@canany()` does exist.

Comment: You're correct! I was not aware of that since I'm still mostly coding with 5.5 :) 
Will definitely remember this :)

Anyway, for readability purposes, it's better to name gates as verbs. 

`@canany(['administrate', 'moderate'])`

Then you would have to define two gates `administrate` and `moderate`.

Comment: I wouldn't use a roles table, I would rather go for an enumeration with the role directly changed in the users table. The reason for this is that the permissions will be hardcoded in the app so there is no "creating new roles", "deleting roles"...